# How to get content from DynamicAssembly object?

Tags: c#, object, dynamic

So i have a `dynamic object` with some lists inside of it like this:

```
ob
 data
  [0]
    List one
      [...]
  [1]
    List two
      [...]
```

I can't recover the values from the lists, i'm stuck at the data level, i already try this:

```
  object valor = t3.GetProperty("data").GetValue(ob, null);
```

And i got one object with this structure:

```
valor
  [0]
    List one
      [...]
  [1]
    List two
      [...]
```

How can i get inside the lists inside of it?
Sorry about the question, but i already spend some hours searching example's of consuming data from objects and nothings seems to work.

Comment: Your object `Valor` is inside `ob` too?

Comment: No, i was creating a new one, but with the same structure, only 1 level inside, in this case, valor = data

Comment: @Lucio_Zenir updated my Answer, see if thata works

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out with this simples code:

```
object ob = MyObject;
string datalevel = TheLevelIWant;
                        var data = ob.GetType().GetProperty("data").GetValue(ob);

                        if (data.GetType().IsGenericType)
                        {
                            foreach(object obj in (data as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList())
                            {
                                ob = obj.GetType().GetProperty(datalevel);
                            }
                        }
```

With this code i have to search in every level for the fields that i want to get the values from.
Just need to add recursive method to do this.